# how to continue downloading .part file

Tags: download

How to continue downloading .part file. I am downloading a trial of windows home server but when I turned the computer on. It said that the download could not continue.
How can I continue it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most download accelerators create a PARTial file while they are working with the download.

- It is important that the context of the download be retained to successfully continue later.
  <sup>So, just having the '`.part`' file handy will not be sufficient.</sup>
  As an example, I usually divert all my downloads from firefox to an accelerator which also creates partial files in progress. I can pause any download, completely shutdown the browser and my machine to continue from there in another session.
- Another catch here is, the server hosting such a file should be able to support a 'continue' option.
  Some servers will not allow a continue and the entire file will need to be downloaded again.
  <sup>However, i do not expect the windows download servers to have this limitation</sup>
  The firefox example I gave earlier does not work on some servers...

Answer (score 2):

If your GUI program that created your partfile doesn't offer you a way to continue the download, you can try to resume it from the command line with wget (I think you can get that on Windows).

```
wget --continue YOUR_URL -O YOUR_PART_FILE
```

The result will depend if the part file is trivial, i.e., something akin to what `wget` would create in the first place and on the capabilities of your file server.

Before trying this, you should back up your partfile (if you've been waiting on it for a long time) and once finished (if it picks up), it might be a good idea to run some checksum on it, if that is available so you know finished download is in an OK condition.

This has worked for me with `chromium's` partfiles on Linux.